# UIButton not responding to click event in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, touch

there is this dark sorcery in ios is preventing my button being clicked. if i don't add button to the uitableviewcell, and i click the button, the event is triggered.
but if the button is in uitableviewcell, it won't get triggered, it seems table
i have sample code ready, if you guys can help me, please just create a simple single-view application in xcode, and just paste the following code

//GRDViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GRDViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView* container;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton* button;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView* tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* arr;

@end
```

//GRDViewController.m

```
#import "GRDViewController.h"

@implementation GRDViewController
@synthesize button, container, arr, tableView;

- (void)_btnTapped {
NSLog(@"TAPPED");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(_btnTapped)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.button setTitle:@"CLICK ME" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  self.arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"123", @"456", @"678", nil];

   self.container = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.button.frame];
  [self.container addSubview:self.button];
  [self.view addSubview:self.container];
  //[self.view  addSubview:self.button];

  self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 400, 400)];

 self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
  self.tableView.delegate = self;
  self.tableView.dataSource = self;

  [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

self.tableView.backgroundColor  = [UIColor redColor];





}



   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"coolcell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
      //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

      UIButton * btn =  [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
         [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(_btnTapped)   forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btn setTitle:[self.arr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
         }

    return cell; 
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [self.arr count];      
}
 @end
```

please help
i feel this case should be common in ios, but nobody has solution for this???

edit: when click on the button it prints NSLOG msg in the xcode console...so make sure...u r looking at the results there...

Comment: Just a suggestion but why not create the button in the interface builder and map an IBAction to its touchUpInside event? Could make the job easier. Also have you tried using gesture recognizers instead? Im guessing that the container is first recieving the touch event and its not passing it to its subviews because perhaps its user interaction flag is disabled. Sorry Im not with my mac right but hope these suggestion helps!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have not given any control event to button .Change it to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` from `UIControlStateNormal`

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `UIControlStateNormal` for ControlEvents use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` like this

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(_btnTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: thanks...for replying that was the issue. i would accept both answer if i can, i vote up ur answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

`[btn.titleLabel setUserInteractionEnabled: NO];`