# How to add a clickable button on table cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I am adding a button in table view cell dynamically. Button shown on table but I am not able to click on them. Here is my Code,

This my tableviewcell class code:

MessageTableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MessageTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
{IBOutlet UIButton *chat_pic_btn;}}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *chat_pic_btn;
@end;
```

MessageTableViewCell.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {chat_pic_btn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
[self.contentView addSubview:chat_pic_btn];}}
```

MessageTable.m

```
-(void)customActionPressed :(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Button Pressed" 
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"You pressed the custom button on cell"]  
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Great" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    MessageTableViewCell *cell = (MessageTableViewCell *)[myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        // cell = [[MessageTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [[MessageTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
cell.chat_pic_btn.frame = CGRectMake(180, 24, 70,35);
            [cell.chat_pic_btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [cell.chat_pic_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
return cell;
}
```

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this button on every view? Is it rendered properly?

Comment: Ya there is a condition if the condition is true then button will shown on view. Button is shown properly but I am not able to call a method on click.

Comment: You should probably also show the code you use to create the table cells. Also, what happens when you click on the button cell? Is there a crash? Or no effect at all?

Comment: Could you put that code in your question?

Comment: why do you add you button like an accessory? you should add your button to your cell directly as a simple subview, like `[cell addSubview:chat_pic_btn];`... have you tried this way already?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest you delete your Button outlet in your TableViewCell. and just create your button dynamically in cellForRowAtIndexPath:
I created a SampleCell Class, subclass of UITableViewCell, it has a UILabel outlet i called "lbl."
This should work on your code, assuming that your selector is on the same class where you put your tablview;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SampleCell";
    SampleCell *cell = (SampleCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SampleCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (SampleCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    cell.lbl.text = @"Hello";
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    //set the position of the button
    button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + 100, cell.frame.origin.y + 20, 100, 30);
    [button setTitle:@"World" forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: hmm strange.. I coded it a while ago.. did you delete your IBOutlet UIButton *btn in your TableViewCell Class?

Comment: Use cell.bounds.origin, not cell.frame.origin for the button's frame.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to Set UserInteraction to YES in cell view and your button

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *yourBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)];
[yourBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(submitBtnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

cell.accessoryView = yourBtn;
```

Comment: sorry, its my mistake when I post question. But its not working...and the code line which u have provide its also not working. This is my method which I have called -(IBAction) show_chat_pic:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"in show");
    UIImageView *imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 310, 320)];
    imageview.image=sender_profile2;
    [self.view addSubview:imageview];
}

Answer (score 1):

http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/05/01/iphone-custom-button-within-a-uitableviewcell/

This May help you

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any control event to the button or Change it to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` from `UIControlStateNormal` and do it only once :)

Comment: i think I have gave the event [cell.chat_pic_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(show_chat_pic:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Check this link then and try and modify your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732229/uibutton-not-responding-to-click-event-in-uitableviewcell